# Function Takes While To Continue After Receiving Response

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, httpresponse

I am trying to handle a response from server, and I receive the response, however, it takes a while to continue the rest.. Surprisingly, printing stuff works fine and I check the realtime server changes, and it also works fine. So it's caused by the xcode.

After receiving the response and check if it's success or not, I check..

```
  // Received HTTP Response

  if let status = json["status"].string {

        if status == "success" {
                   print("C")  
                   activityView.stopAnimating()
                   activityView.removeFromSuperview()

                   self.someAnimation()
                   print("D")
        } else {
            ...
        }
   }
```

Surprisingly C & D gets printed instantly, but activity animation doesn't seem to stop in between. It takes like 10 more seconds to get completed and stop and remove activityIndicator. The custom animation `someAnimation()` also continues as the same time with the activityIndicator.

I understand it's an asynchronous thread, but doesn't it has to stop activityIndicator and continue as it reaches `print("D")`?

Comment: I think you answered it in your own question. It's asynchronous -- someAnimation is called, and then the statement is printed.

Comment: Make sure you are calling activityView.stopAnimating() on main thread not on background thread.

Comment: you'd better to make all UI stuff in main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are performing UI tasks on a background thread which results in an undefined behaviour. One way to avoid this is to wrap your UI method calls in a `dispatch_async`:

```
// Received HTTP Response

if let status = json["status"].string {

    if status == "success" {
               print("C")  
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    activityView.stopAnimating()
                    activityView.removeFromSuperview()

                    self.someAnimation()
               });

               print("D")
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives an error for me `'^' is not a prefix unary operator` :/

Comment: No problem. I fixed the answer.